# How is "16.7 million colors" in a display calculated?

Tags: computer-hardware

How is "16.7 million colors" in a display calculated?

Also, is it a software or a hardware thing (the 16.7 million colors)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each color red, green, blue that makes a pixel has a range of 0 to 255. So each of the colors has 256 possible settings. 256*256*256=16.77 million possible colors.

Comment: How do they know that each RGB sequence is an unique color? Or do they merely "guess" that "maybe it produces ~16.7 million *distinct* colors".

Comment: There are an infinite number of colours - the standard RGB division of 0 to 255 intensity increments is arbitrary and based on 8bit data architecture. We could just as well divide the colour intensities into 1024 shades in which  case we would have 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1073 MILLION distinct colours.